# On time evolution of density operator (matrix) in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, density-operator, time-evolution

Suppose I have at time $t=0$ a statistical ensemble of quantum states
$$\{|\psi_n\rangle\langle\psi_n|\}_{n=1}^N$$
The probability of finding the result $a$ for an observable $A$ in this ensemble is given by the Born rule (assuming discrete spectrum, without degeneracy):

$$ \sum_{n=1}^N p_n \langle \psi_n | \Pi_a|\psi_n \rangle = \operatorname{Tr}\left[\rho\,\Pi_a\right]$$

where $\Pi_a$ is the projector in the $a$-eigenspace of $A$, and

$$
\rho:= \sum_{n=1}^N p_n |\psi_n\rangle\langle\psi_n|
$$
is the density operator or density matrix.

At time $t>0$, this density $\rho$ takes the form

$$
\rho(t):= \sum_{n=1}^N p_n |\psi_n(t)\rangle\langle\psi_n(t)|
$$

what puzzles me the most is that those $p_n$ stay the same. Why should I expect that? Why couldn't the probabilities change as each state $|\psi_n(t)\rangle\langle\psi_n(t)|$ evolves with time?

Comment: I don't understand. *If* your ensemble is "created" (e.g. you have some probabilistic preparation scheme) in the sense that at $t_0$ your system is associated a wave function $|\psi_n\rangle$ with probability $p_n$, then the probability that your system at time $t$ is in $|\psi_n(t)\rangle$ is still $p_n$ - simply because the time evolution is unitary/deterministic!

Comment: From what I've understood, $p_n$ is the probability of finding the eigenvalue $a$ in the $n$-th state $|\psi_n\rangle\langle\psi_n|$ at time $t=0$. But... if the $n$-th state evolves, together with all the other $N-1$, who tells me that $p_n$ couldn't also change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is really just that you start out with a statistical ensemble, i.e. the quantum system is in the state $\lvert \psi_n\rangle$ with probability $p_n$ at the start. The density matrix $\sum_n p_n\lvert \psi_n\rangle\langle \psi_n\rvert$ is just a way to summarize this information into a single object. The notion of density matrices does not add any new "mechanics" to quantum mechanics.

Each of these states evolves in time like quantum states normally do, i.e. $\lvert \psi_n(t)\rangle = U(t)\lvert \psi_n\rangle$ with $U(t)$ the ordinary time evolution operator. So if the system started in the state $\lvert \psi_n(0)\rangle$, of course it is in the state $\lvert \psi_n(t)\rangle$ at time $t$. Since it had probability $p_n$ to start in the state $\lvert \psi_n(0)\rangle$, it still has probability $p_n$ to be in $\lvert \psi_n(t)\rangle$ at time $t$, and the density matrix at time $t$ is $\sum_n p_n\lvert \psi_n(t)\rangle\langle \psi_n(t)\rvert$. There isn't anything more to this, the probabilities here just act like classical probabilities.

Comment: I might explain my doubt with an example I made up, hoping not to make things worse. Suppose at time $t=0$ I have a coin. Its density matrix is $\rho= 1/2 |H \rangle\langle H| + 1/2|T \rangle\langle T|$. But suppose that this coin has a hidden engine at time $t>0$ that makes heads come out more frequently than tails. Evidently $p_H(t) > p_H(0)=1/2$

Comment: @ric.san Quantum mechanics does not model the flip of a classical coin. I do not understand your comment.

Comment: The classical analogy was just a pretext to say I can't see a good reason on assuming  $p_n(t)=p_n$. But it's clearly my fault, since this expression for $\rho(t)$ leads to the quantum Liouville equation, so it must be right of course

Comment: @ric.san We're not "assuming $p_n(t) = p_n$". We're just saying "we start with a system which can be in a bunch of different states with probability $p_n$ at $t=0$" and see what we get when we apply ordinary QM time evolution to that", that's the point of my answer.